# Get position of selected TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with the following XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="tree">
    <TreeView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="F2"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </TreeView.InputBindings>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}">
                    <Label.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename" 
                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Label.ContextMenu>
                    <Label.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                    </Label.InputBindings>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

On a click on Rename (or pressing on F2) on a `TreeViewItem` I want to replace the Label with a `TextBox`.

What is the best way to do this?

I've already tried to get the `Position` or `Bounds` of the SelectedItem of the `TreeView` but that is an instance of Folder, so I can't get the information there.

Comment: you could use a `Control` and set it's `Template` in a `Style`. In the Style you use `ControlTemplate` with the Content that suits the condition. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a better way to implement your required functionality is to permanently use a `TextBox`, but with its `IsReadOnly` property set to true. Instead of swapping your `Label` for a `TextBox`, you can then just set the `TextBox.IsReadOnly` property to `True` to make it editable.

Furthermore, you can also add `Style Setter`s to make the `TextBox` look like it is not a `TextBox` when it is not editable:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You could then data bind a `bool IsEditable` property from your code behind or view model to change whether the `TextBox` should be editable or not:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditable}" ... />
```

Then all you need to do to make the field editable is this (in your code behind or view model):

```
IsEditable = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You most create a UserControl with editable mode like combobox and change the mode run-time.
For some similar purpose i changed the combobox template and built my own control.

By the way i suggest take a look at combobox control template. (IsEditable or Not)